# Lista de arreglos multidimensionales en c#

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de crear un vector de dos posiciones, en donde en cada posición agrego una matriz de dos dimensiones de tipo `string`, lo que me llevo a crear una lista de arreglos de dos dimensiones de la siguiente manera:

```
List<String[,]> multi = new List<string[,]>();
```

luego cree mi matriz bidimensional y le agregue los valores de la siguiente manera solo como ejemplo:

```
string[,] m2 = new string[2, 2];

m2[0, 0] = "jose";
m2[0, 1] = "juan";
m2[1, 0] = "luis";
m2[1, 1] = "pedro";
```

después agrege ese matriz a la lista de la siguiente manera:

```
multi.Add(m2);
```

El problema aquí es que cuando quiero pasar mi lista a un `array` con el método `toArray()` de la siguiente manera, me marca error:

```
string[] main = multi.ToArray();
```

La pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo hacerle para que esa lista se convierta en un `array`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema está en el tipo de datos que le asignas a main.

Al convertir multi a Array lo que te va a devolver es un Array de matrices, no un Array de strings:

```
string[][,] main = multi.ToArray();
```

Comment: entiendo, muchas gracias.